# Convergence of integer powers of stochastic matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am studying Markov Chains from these [lecture notes](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/ton.coolen/allnotes/MarkovChains.pdf).
In the sections on convergence to stationary states and time averages, there are some results that are stated as trivial.

Namely, these are the claim that for $\mathbf{P}$ a stochastic matrix the limit Q defined as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}^n = \mathbf{Q}$$
if it exists is stochastic itself.

There are also results on convergence of time averages.

I would like to prove these results rigorously as an exercise and am therefore wondering what metric is used to define the convergence of sequences in $\mathit{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, the set of $n\times n$ real matrices.

Comment: The product of two stochastic matrices is again a stochastic matrix (say row stochastic). Therefore $P^n$ is stochastic. The functions $A\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}$ are continuous from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ These functions are constantly $1$ on stochastic matrices. So if the limit exists the resulting matrix is row stochastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequences in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ can inherit the same metrics as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ (e.g. the usual ones induced by the $\ell_p$ norms) since we can simply think of the matrix as a long vector of numbers. There are other [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) which use the structure of the matrix; but all norms are equivalent on finite-dimensional spaces so they describe the same convergence phenomena.

As mentioned in Ryszard's comment, you can prove that $P^m$ is stochastic for all $m \geq 1$ (e.g. by induction). Then this will imply that the limit $Q$, if it exists, must also be stochastic (e.g. considering the continuous function in the comment, or equivalently arguing that you would get a contradiction otherwise).